# Integrate JSEP in WebRTC Demo

Tags: websocket, webrtc

I have found this [video conferencing prototype](http://blog.gingertech.net/2012/06/04/video-conferencing-in-html5-webrtc-via-web-sockets/). But I cannot get it to run since the ROAP protocol has been replaced with JSEP.

I have tried to solve the problem using the following sources:

[Example ROAP and JSEP](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webrtc/2012Jan/0093.html)

[ROAP on JSEP](http://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/trunk/roap-jsep/roap_on_jsep.js)

I think a lot of people would appreciate to have one working JSEP example to built on.

```
<script>
  var socket = new WebSocket('ws://mydomain.com:1337');
  var sourcevid = document.getElementById('sourcevid');
  var remotevid = document.getElementById('remotevid');
  var localStream = null;
  var peerConn = null;
  var started = false;

  var logg = function(s) { console.log(s); };

  // when PeerConn is created, send setup data to peer via WebSocket
  function onSignal(message) {
      logg("Sending setup signal");
      socket.send(message);
  }

  // when remote adds a stream, hand it on to the local video element
  function onRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
    logg("Added remote stream");
    remotevid.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  }

  // when remote removes a stream, remove it from the local video element
  function onRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
    logg("Remove remote stream");
    remotevid.src = "";
  }

  function createPeerConnection() {
    try {
      logg("Creating peer connection");
      peerConn = new webkitDeprecatedPeerConnection("STUN stun.l.google.com:19302", onSignal);
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        peerConn = new webkitPeerConnection00("STUN stun.l.google.com:19302", onSignal);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: " + e.message);
      }
    }
    peerConn.addEventListener("addstream", onRemoteStreamAdded, false);
    peerConn.addEventListener("removestream", onRemoteStreamRemoved, false)
  }

  // start the connection upon user request
  function connect() {
    if (!started && localStream) {
      createPeerConnection();
      logg('Adding local stream...');
      peerConn.addStream(localStream);
      started = true;
    } else {
      alert("Local stream not running yet.");
    }
  }

  // accept connection request
  socket.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);
  function onMessage(evt) {
    logg("RECEIVED: "+evt.data);
    if (!started) {
      createPeerConnection();
      logg('Adding local stream...');
      peerConn.addStream(localStream);
      started = true;
    }
    // Message returned from other side
    logg('Processing signaling message...');
    peerConn.processSignalingMessage(evt.data);
  }

  function hangUp() {
    logg("Hang up.");
    peerConn.close();
    peerConn = null;
    started = false;
  }

  function startVideo() {
      // Replace the source of the video element with the stream from the camera
      try { //try it with spec syntax
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, successCallback, errorCallback);
      } catch (e) {
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia("video,audio", successCallback, errorCallback);
      }
      function successCallback(stream) {
          sourcevid.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
          localStream = stream;
      }
      function errorCallback(error) {
          console.error('An error occurred: [CODE ' + error.code + ']');
      }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    sourcevid.src = "";
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example at [apprtc.appspot.com](http://apprtc.appspot.com) shows WebRTC in action with JSEP.

There is also a [ROAP to JSEP library](http://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/roap-jsep) that abstracts DeprecatedPeerConnection while using the JSEP API.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry – added answer quickly via my phone while on the train! Have now added more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I just don't understand how I can use a webSocket to communicate between the two peers using the ROAP to JSEP library (in this case pc1 & pc2).

Comment: WebSocket can be used for signaling, via an intermediary server, whereas the actual communication of streaming data between peers is done with RTCPeerConnection. Signaling is the 'handshaking'/initiation process of exchanging network and media data between peers. (Peers also need to discover each other -- like meeting participants sharing a conference call number -- and in examples like http://apprtc.appspot.com, that's done simply by the 'caller' giving the 'callee' a URL that has an identifier.) Once all that's successfully completed, RTCPeerConnection can do its P2P magic.